# Retrofit2 MySQL duplicated @POST requests with new Android Studio 3.6

Tags: mysql, android-studio, retrofit2

so long...

I´m getting mad about an Android Studio 3.6 update.
I didn´t touch the code during update. Before, it was working all fine, but when updated to 3.6, it seems Retrofit2 makes my @POST in client repeat, so if I´m tying to add a new user to DB, it inserts, but then do it some more times, so I get into response failure, and so it says "user already exists". As I said it´s not a coding matter, as it worked fine until update.
Anyone cry with me?
Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue, quite frustrating